# Extract substring using regular expression on a Unix file

Tags: sed, grep, awk, regular-expression

I have file with below contents .

```
/ABC/RTE/AD_900_VOP_123/OPP
/ABC/RTE/TRE/AD_900_VOP_145/BBB
/ABC/RTE/AN_900_VFP_124/FBF
/ABC/RTE/HD_900_FOP_153/WEW
/ABD/RDV/AD_900_VOP_123/OPP
/ABC/RTE/WD_900_VOP_123/GRR/TRD
/ABC/RTE/RTD/AR_900_VOP_443/SDD
```

How can I use regular expression on this file such that I get the output such as

```
AD_900_VOP_123
AD_900_VOP_145
AN_900_VFP_124
HD_900_FOP_153
AD_900_VOP_123
WD_900_VOP_123
AR_900_VOP_443
```

Comment: What is the criterion for picking the field of interest?

Comment: criteria is any pattern like `<alphabets>_<digits>_<alphabets>_<digits>` and fall between two `/`

Comment: awk -F/ '{print $3}'

Comment: `awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}'` to find last dir (if those are dirs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gnu grep

```
grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]+_[[:digit:]]+_[[:alpha:]]+_[[:digit:]]+'
```

Use the perl-regex flag and look-behind and look-ahead assertions to guarantee that the match is surrounded by `/`

```
grep -oP '(?<=/)[[:alpha:]]+_[[:digit:]]+_[[:alpha:]]+_[[:digit:]]+(?=/)'
```

Answer (score 3):

IMHO Perl offers the easiest and the most flexible solution:

```
perl -nE 'say $1 if m{/(\w+\d+\w+\d+)/};' input_file
```

Please note that `input_file` is optional: `STDIN` will be filtered if/when input file name is not given.

Answer (score 2):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk -F/ '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$0=($i~/_/)?$i:$0}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.

Contents of `tstfile.txt`:

```
/ABC/RTE/AD_900_VOP_123/OPP
/ABC/RTE/TRE/AD_900_VOP_145/BBB
/ABC/RTE/AN_900_VFP_124/FBF
/ABC/RTE/HD_900_FOP_153/WEW
/ABD/RDV/AD_900_VOP_123/OPP
/ABC/RTE/WD_900_VOP_123/GRR/TRD
/ABC/RTE/RTD/AR_900_VOP_443/SDD
```

Command to transform `tstfile.txt`:

```
$ sed 's|.*/\([0-9_A-Z]\+900[0-9_A-Z]\+\)/.*|\1|' tstfile.txt
AD_900_VOP_123
AD_900_VOP_145
AN_900_VFP_124
HD_900_FOP_153
AD_900_VOP_123
WD_900_VOP_123
AR_900_VOP_443
```

#### explanation

The above extracts everything that's touching the "900" up to the first forward slash encountered at the beginning of "900" (left of the 9), and everything up to the first forward slash at the end of "900" (right of the last 0).

Comment: can you please explain it in one or two lines

Comment: Hi,I just ran it ,but I get the entire input as the result 
`$ sed 's|.*/\([0-9_A-Z]\+900[0-9_A-Z]\+\)/.*|\1|' tstfile.tx`t
`/ABC/RTE/AD_900_VOP_123/OPP`
`/ABC/RTE/TRE/AD_900_VOP_145/BBB`
`/ABC/RTE/AN_900_VFP_124/FBF`
`/ABC/RTE/HD_900_FOP_153/WEW`
`/ABD/RDV/AD_900_VOP_123/OPP`
`/ABC/RTE/WD_900_VOP_123/GRR/TRD`
`/ABC/RTE/RTD/AR_900_VOP_443/SDD`

Comment: No ,I am not :)

Comment: did you run it ?

Comment: @g4ur4v - Sorry I had to ask 8-). What version of sed are you using? I just ran what you sent me and it worked just fine. You can use this command: `sed --version` GNU sed version 4.2.1.

Comment: I am using mobaxterm on windows may be thats why I am not getting the desire result. `$ sed --version`
`This is not GNU sed version 4.0`

Comment: @g4ur4v - Ah that makes more sense. MobaXterm doesn't include a 4.x GNU version of `sed`. I've updated your question to include a new tag for MobaXterm so that others are aware that you're using it - and that the Q&A are specific to that.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's|.*/\([^/]*_[^/]*\)/.*|\1|
' <<\INPUT
/ABC/RTE/AD_900_VOP_123/OPP 
/ABC/RTE/TRE/AD_900_VOP_145/BBB 
/ABC/RTE/AN_900_VFP_124/FBF 
/ABC/RTE/HD_900_FOP_153/WEW 
/ABD/RDV/AD_900_VOP_123/OPP 
/ABC/RTE/WD_900_VOP_123/GRR/TRD 
/ABC/RTE/RTD/AR_900_VOP_443/SDD
INPUT
```

That will remove up to the second to last occurrence of `/` immediately preceding a `_` character on a line, save everything between there and the next occurrence of `/`, and then remove the rest.

The above command prints....

```
AD_900_VOP_123 
AD_900_VOP_145 
AN_900_VFP_124 
HD_900_FOP_153 
AD_900_VOP_123 
WD_900_VOP_123 
AR_900_VOP_443
```

Comment: A variation on this which is slightly longer but 100 times easier to read (and write!) is `sed 's|.*/\(.._..._..._...\)/.*|\1|' <input`

Comment: @Johan - it is also far less capable - your version strictly delimits each field, mine will work with fields of any length. And I don't consider it easier to read or write.

Answer (score 0):

The parts you do not want have a slash and three characters.

The part that you want to keep also starts with a slash and have more than three characters, but the third character is an underscore, so we delete all the parts that look like `/XXX` but not `/XX_`

This leaves the leading slash on the part that we want to keep, so we finally also delete that one slash.

`sed 's|/..[^_]||g; s|^/||' </tmp/f1`

**Explanation:**

The sed command is made up of two `s` (substitute commands) separated by `;`.  Since we have slash in the regular expression, I use `s|...|...|` in stead of the regular `s/.../.../`

Both of the substitute commands have the second part empty - substitute with nothing = delete that part. The first one uses a `g` for global, in other words do it over and over until there is nothing to substitute.

The `[^_]` matches anything except an underscore.
T

Comment: Using `.` like that in a `g`lobal is *usually* looking for trouble. What if one of the fields winds up being only a single char? That field *(and one or two that follow)* goes *poof*. `sed 's|/[^/_]\{3\}||g'` would at least serve to ensure that you don't remove anything you shouldn't, though in some cases might result in your not removing something you should, which is usually the better alternative, as I consider it.

Comment: @mikeserv It handles the sample data provided, not all possible types of data.